# Install Docker in container for use by GitLab CI build

Tags: maven, docker, gitlab, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I'm new to Docker, but have a Java web app project for which my Maven build produces and installs a Docker image. i.e.

```
mvn clean install
```

Produces:

```
REPOSITORY                             TAG                  IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
registry.gitlab.com/me/myapp   0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-dev   12d69e5ab28b        45 minutes ago      666 MB
```

I'm making use of Spotify's Maven plugin to build this, which I can then deploy to the repository using:

```
mvn docker:push
```

Which works great. **However:** I'm using GitLab for CI, and my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file contains:

```
image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

build:
  script: "mvn clean install && mvn docker:push"
```

This nearly works, but fails as Docker is not installed *in my container* which is running the build:

```
[INFO] Building image registry.gitlab.com/me/myapp
Dec 31, 2016 8:30:45 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: No such file or directory
Dec 31, 2016 8:30:45 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->unix://localhost:80
Dec 31, 2016 8:30:45 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->unix://localhost:80: No such file or directory
... (more of the same) ...
```

It seems the solution here is to install Docker into the container. I can't find a pre-built image that has Java, Maven *and* Docker, but I did try configuring Docker as a service:

```
services:
  - docker:1.13-rc
```

But the result is the same - it seems services are meant to be used as external services that can be *connected to*, but that are not immediately installed within the same container.

**How should I go about** updating my `.yml` file so that the GitLab build can build and push a Docker image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're very close.

Gitlab works in *stages*, and you've correctly defined a proper `build` stage for your java app. However, you need another stage that will then build your docker image. I'm not all that familiar with Maven and what's configured for your `mvn docker:push` step, but I'm going to assume that it's a pretty simple wrapper around the `docker build` and `docker push` commands.

I'd recommend separating things out into different stages and using artifacts to transfer the built files between containers.

I'd imagine your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file should look something like this:

```
image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8
stages:
  - build_application
  - build_image

# This stage builds your application
build_application:
  stage: build_application
  script:
    - mvn clean install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - my-application.jar

build_image:
    image: docker:latest
    services:
      - docker:dind
    stage: build_image
    # Remember that even though the JAR file was built in a separate image
    #  Gitlab CI will make it available in this image because I specified it in artifacts
    #
    # All I really need to build the Docker image is the artifact(s) & Dockerfile
    script:
      - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
      - docker build --no-cache=true -t registry.gitlab.com/me/myapp .
      - docker push registry.gitlab.com/me/myapp
```

Comment: This is super helpful Ben, thank you for the clarification - I'll give things a quick spin and let you know how it goes.

Comment: This is the solution I came up with too. However, I would be interested in seeing a solution that works with the docker maven plugin.

Comment: @rolve It's certainly possible, but more involved. What you have to do is have an image that has both `mvn` and `docker`. I'd look at the Dockerfiles of each image in order to create another image that is fit for your purpose.

Comment: I ended up creating my own image by starting up `maven:3-jdk-8`, installing `docker`, and then pushing it as my own `craigotis/buildtools:v1` image. It's been working well so far - the only thing I really don't like is my Maven build downloading the entire `~/.m2` repository for each build. I'm considering updating my image to start with a pre-populated repository folder - since  my dependency versions rarely change, and now I can build without needing internet access.

Comment: If you want to make your image more generic, you could always utilise [Gitlab CI Cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#cache) so that your dependencies are cached. However, you'd need to make sure that the dependencies are downloaded in the project directory.